# Работает ли C# 8.0 в VS 2019 Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, c#-8.0

На днях вышла Preview версия VS 2019.

Я скачал ее с целью пощупать новые новые фичи C# 8.0, но что-то ничего не работает из того, что они анонсировали в начале года.

Полноценный C# 8.0 еще не завезли туда?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/05/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/

Comment: Чтоб не плодить вопросы, задам тут, а в 2019 c++ clr intelisense по прежнему подчеркивает все красным при каждом телодвижении?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите настройки языка в свойствах проекта. Как например [здесь](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St).

Comment: Поставил там 8,0 Beta. Но все равно, Range'ей нету, новый синтаксис расширителей не работает...

Comment: Все верно. Beta же